# C++ beginner: Passing a pointer of b2Body to function by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, box2d

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to pass a b2Body (Box2d object) to a method by reference and assign it a value.

```
void GameContactListener::GetContactInfo(b2Body &hero, b2Body &ground, b2Body &enemy) {
    b2Body *b1 = thing1->GetBody();
    b2Body *b2 = thing2->GetBody();

    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
    hero = *b1;
    ground = *b2;
}

// elsewhere
b2Body *hero = NULL;
b2Body *ground = NULL;

GetContactInfo(*hero, *ground);
```

I can get pass by reference working for simple `int` types but seem to be missing something with pointers.

Edit, adding declaration of method:

```
void GetContactInfo(b2Body& hero,  b2Body& ground, b2Body& enemy);
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `GetContactInfo`?  You are passing dereferenced pointers.  In order to take these as references you would need `GetContactInfo(b2Body&, b2Body&);` or maybe `GetContactInfo(const b2Body&, const b2Body&);` if this function doesn't change the arguments.

Comment: Added the declaration.  I wanted this function to change the arguments, in order to do something like a multiple value return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `thing->GetBody()` returns a `b2Body*`, then

```
void GameContactListener::GetContactInfo(b2Body*& hero, b2Body*& ground) {
    hero = thing->GetBody();
    ground = thing->GetBody();
}

// elsewhere
b2Body* hero = NULL;
b2Body* ground = NULL;

GetContactInfo(hero, ground);
```

Note that both `hero` and `ground` will point t the same `b2Body` object.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  Meant to use `thing1` and `thing2`, instead of `thing`.  Fixed in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(b2Body*&)` to pass a reference to pointer.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked, but it looked like @juanchopanza answered first.

Answer (score 0):

In your call you should pass the address of the pointer like below:

```
 GetContactInfo(hero, ground);
```

I advice you to read section 4 in [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/c-understanding-pointers).

Comment: When I try that, I get `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'b2Body' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'b2Body *'`

Comment: Yes, you are pointing addresses to values, tries this :
    `hero = b1;
    ground = b2;`

Answer (score 0):

Use reference to pointer to change the pointer as others have pointed out.

```
void
GameContactListener::GetContactInfo(b2Body *& hero, b2Body *& ground)
{
    b2Body *b1 = thing->GetBody();
    b2Body *b2 = thing->GetBody();

    // Assign pointer to ref to pointer here.
    hero = b1;
    ground = b2;
}

// elsewhere
b2Body *hero = NULL;
b2Body *ground = NULL;

GetContactInfo(hero, ground); // Pass pointers
```

Another old-fashioned way is pointer to pointer:

```
void
GameContactListener::GetContactInfo(b2Body **hero, b2Body **ground) {
    b2Body *b1 = thing->GetBody();
    b2Body *b2 = thing->GetBody();

    // Assign pointers to pointers.
    *hero = b1;
    *ground = b2;
}

// elsewhere
b2Body *hero = NULL;
b2Body *ground = NULL;

GetContactInfo(&hero, &ground); // Pass address of pointers.
```

I like the first way better as it's cleaner and more modern.